# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EmptyPartition1[Model]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Model]' using EFCore.BulkExtensions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, casting, bulkupdate

I'm using EFCore 7.0 and EFCoreBulkExtensions 7.1.2

When I'm trying to execute a

```
_context.BulkUpdate(list, bulkConfig);
```

It thows an `<System.InvalidCastException>`:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EmptyPartition1[ModelX]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ModelX]'
```

the list is not empty, it has elements of ModelX class

Any clue about this?

I already tried passing the list as List<>, IList<> and IEnumerable<> and getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the .BulkUpdate() method by an .UpdateRange()

from this

`_context.BulkUpdate(list, bulkConfig);`

to this

`_context.UpdateRange(list);`

`_context.SaveChanges();`

and now it's working, hopefully helps another lost developer looking for light :D